# findContours and drawContours errors in opencv 3 beta/python

Tags: python, opencv

I try to run an example from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#contours-getting-started).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('final.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```

The error is

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "E:\PC\opencv3Try\findCExample.py", line 7, in <module>
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

If I delete "hierarchy" the error arises in drawContours:

```
TypeError: contours is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

If I use contours[0] in drawContours

```
cv2.error: E:\opencv\opencv\sources\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2171: error: (-215) npoints > 0 in function cv::drawContours
```

What problems could be here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

opencv  3 has a slightly [changed syntax](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) here, the return values differ:

```
cv2.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) → image, contours, hierarchy
```

Comment: OpenCV 3.0 documentation for Python is currently hard to find (the above link currently fails), so I just tried whether `findContours()` in 3.0 still modifies the image.  It does, and the image passed and the image returned are identical according to `is`.

Comment: [Here's](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) a working link to the OpenCV 3.0.0-dev documentation which does show the three return values for the Python version of findContours.

Answer (score 12):

Following on berak's answer, just adding `[-2:]` to `findContours()` calls makes them work for both OpenCV 2.4 and 3.0:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(...)[-2:]
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the OpenCV version, `cv2.findContours()` has varying return signatures.

In OpenCV 3.4.X, [`cv2.findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) returns 3 items

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]])
```

In OpenCV 2.X and 4.1.X, [`cv2.findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) returns 2 items

```
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]])
```

You can easily obtain the contours regardless of the version like this:

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I encounter same problem before and i use this code to fix it.
Im using 3.1 anyway.

```
(_,contours,_) = cv2.findContours(
  thresh.copy(),
  cv2.RETR_LIST,
  cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
)
```