# OpenCV Android Error - CVException

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying `transform perspective` automatically, I'm using a manual from [HERE](https://plus.google.com/115946293009644565263/posts/gjK4i52oZQm)

Exactly the `chapter 4: Flexible perspective transform`

When I get the image to transform I get the next error:

**Error**

```
    11-04 13:34:25.759: E/cv::error()(17332): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (count >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S)) in double cv::arcLength(cv::InputArray, bool), file /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp, line 301
11-04 13:34:25.759: E/org.opencv.imgproc(17332): imgproc::arcLength_10() caught cv::Exception: /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:301: error: (-215) count >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function double cv::arcLength(cv::InputArray, bool)
11-04 13:34:25.759: E/AndroidRuntime(17332): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 13:34:25.759: E/AndroidRuntime(17332): Process: com.example.alvaro.opencv, PID: 17332
11-04 13:34:25.759: E/AndroidRuntime(17332): CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:301: error: (-215) count >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function double cv::arcLength(cv::InputArray, bool)
11-04 13:34:25.759: E/AndroidRuntime(17332): ]
```

**The code**

```
Mat gray = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(sampledImage, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 0);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(gray, gray, new Size(7, 7), 0);

Mat edgeImage = new Mat();
Imgproc.Canny(gray, edgeImage, 100, 200);//1500,300

Mat lines = new Mat();
int threshold = 100;//200
Imgproc.HoughLinesP(edgeImage, lines, 1, Math.PI / 180, threshold, 60, 10);//100,60

ArrayList<org.opencv.core.Point> corners = new ArrayList<org.opencv.core.Point>();

//Find the intersection of the four lines to get the four corners
for (int i = 0; i < lines.cols(); i++)
{
      for (int j = i + 1; j < lines.cols(); j++)
      {
            org.opencv.core.Point intersectionPoint = getLinesIntersection(lines.get(0, i), lines.get(0, j));
            if (intersectionPoint != null)
            {
                  Log.i(TAG, "intersectionPoint: " + intersectionPoint.x + " " + intersectionPoint.y);
                  corners.add(intersectionPoint);
             }
       }
 }

 MatOfPoint2f approxCorners=new MatOfPoint2f(); 
 MatOfPoint2f cornersMat=new MatOfPoint2f();
 cornersMat.fromList(corners);

 //ERROR LINE on "Imgproc.arcLength" 
 double approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(cornersMat, true) * 0.02;

 Imgproc.approxPolyDP(cornersMat, approxCorners,approxDistance, true);
```

**What I tried**

- I tried change image 32bits to 8bits (or another one) without results
- To use another method to her edges.
- I found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33067960/3626214) the same issue, but... really I can't found the solution...

I'm really don't know how I can solve it.